# Tcl regexp expression to catch words outside brackets

Tags: regex, tcl

I want to parse:
`([(A touch B) over C] touch {D touch E}) is good`.

Using:
`( P1 touch P2) is good`.

I want to replace `P1` and `P2` by regular expression to get
`P1 = [(A touch B) over C]
P2 =  {D touch E}`
My first idea is:
`( (.*)  touch (.*)) is good`.

But i got wrong matching:
`P1 = [(A touch B) over C] touch  {D
P2 = E}`

I want to break on the `"touch"` outside the brackets.
Note: `A, B, C... are examples` so we should use `.*`

Comment: Please add the code snippet that you've tried and the current output.

Comment: Try [`\((\[[^][]*]|{[^{}]*}) touch (\[[^][]*]|{[^{}]*})\) is good`](https://regex101.com/r/krFIr7/1). See https://ideone.com/D9r0cV.

Comment: @Wiktor, nice, you should add that as an answer. I'd suggest, for readability, this can be broken into pieces: `set bracketed {\[[^][]*\]}; set braced {\{[^{}]*\}}; set wanted "($bracketed|$braced)"; set re "\\($wanted touch $wanted\\) is good"; lassign [lrange [regexp -all -inline $re $txt] 1 end] first second`

Comment: @Ahmed, note that this will not work properly with nested bracketed text: `{{D touch E} touch F}` -- regular expressions are not powerful enough to parse that.

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression matching can't handle arbitrary expressions of this kind, but most parsers can. In the Tcllib standard library for Tcl there is a PEG (parsing expression grammar) parser generator in the `pt` (parser tools) module. The following defines a grammar (as a simple string) that can parse your example text, and also text where brackets of the same kind are nested:

```
set grammar {
PEG Reader (Datum)
      Datum       <- '(' <space>* P1 'touch' <space>* P2 ') is good' ;
      Word        <- <alpha>+ ;
      BrackExpr   <- '[' Expression+ ']' ;
      BraceExpr   <- '{' Expression+ '}' ;
      ParenExpr   <- '(' Expression+ ')' ;
void: Expression  <- (Word / BrackExpr / BraceExpr / ParenExpr) <space>* ;
      P1          <- Expression ;
      P2          <- Expression ;
END;
}
```

To use this, you need to follow some steps. First save the generated parser in a file:

```
package require fileutil
package require pt::pgen

fileutil::writeFile ./reader.tcl [pt::pgen peg $grammar oo -class Reader]
```

This code creates a file, reader.tcl, that contains a TclOO class that perform the parsing specified in the grammar. You `source` up that file to make the class available:

```
source reader.tcl
```

If you are going to do that multiple times from the console, you need to destroy the class in between:

```
catch {Reader destroy} ; source reader.tcl
```

Then you make an instance of the class and put it to work:

```
Reader create reader
set str {([(A touch B) over C] touch {D touch E}) is good}
reader parset $str
```

(If you use the `parse` method instead, you can parse an open channel.)

The result of the parsing is the AST (abstract syntax tree)

```
Datum 0 47 {P1 1 21} {P2 28 38}
```

As you can see, it has found text for P1 at string indices 1 to 21, and for P2 at 28 to 38 (note that trailing whitespace is captured). You can use `string range $str 1 21` to get the text for P1, or automate it:

```
proc Datum {from to args} {foreach arg $args {puts [uplevel 1 $arg]}}
proc P1 {from to} {string range $::str $from $to}
proc P2 {from to} {string range $::str $from $to}

% Datum 0 47 {P1 1 21} {P2 28 38}
[(A touch B) over C]
{D touch E}
```

If you use this, you might want to experiment with the definition of the nonterminal `Word`. Currently it only allows alphabetic characters. A definition like

```
      Word        <- (<alnum> / [;:/&!?*+.\'\"#])+ ;
```

allows digits and some punctuation too. There are more inclusive character sets, but `<punct>`, `<graph>`, and `<print>` all contain bracket characters. Even if the definition of `Expression` is changed

```
void: Expression  <- (BrackExpr / BraceExpr / ParenExpr / Word) <space>* ;
```

so that `Word` comes last, which lets the parser choose one of the `*Expr` nonterminals on encountering an opening bracket, the closing bracket will still be consumed by `Word` and not by the correct nonterminal expression. AFAICT this is a limitation of PEG parsers, which do not backtrack. The grammar can be modified to deal with this, but it will very quickly become too complicated.

Documentation:
[pt (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/apps/pt.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may use a regex pattern that will match either a `[...]` or `{...}` substrings before `touch` and then the same pattern after.

It will look like

```
\((\[[^][]*]|{[^{}]*}) touch (\[[^][]*]|{[^{}]*})\) is good
```

See the [regex demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/krFIr7/1).
The `(\[[^][]*]|{[^{}]*})` construct is a capturing group that matches either a `[` + 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]` or a `{` followed with 0+ chars other than `{` and `}` and then `}`.

One remark: there is no way to match *nested balanced bracketed substrings* with Tcl regex.

When using Tcl code, you may build the regex dynamically:

```
set txt {([(A touch B) over C] touch {D touch E}) is good}
set squares {\[[^][]*\]}
set braces {\{[^{}]*\}}
set cap "($squares|$braces)"
set rx "\\($cap touch $cap\\) is good"; 
lassign [lrange [regexp -all -inline $rx $txt] 1 end] P1 P2
puts "$P1 ::: $P2"
```

Output: `[(A touch B) over C] ::: {D touch E}`.

See the [Tcl online demo](https://ideone.com/wIEieT).